Formula validation on Field service lightning mobile app
I am trying to validate a number field on the FSL app which should accept only 10 digits and check for the format of mobile numbers like  '1234567890' or '(123) 456-7890'. Following all the rules and limitations as per the FSL guidelines. When I test the same on UI works as expected and I see a validation error if the user enters <10 or only with one '('.
here is my formula:

(NOT((LEN(({!Phone_Number})) = 11 && BEGINS(({!Phone_Number}), '(') &&
ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(({!Phone_Number}), '(',
'')))||(LEN(({!Phone_Number})) = 11 && CONTAINS(({!Phone_Number}),
')') && ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(({!Phone_Number}), ')',
''))))&&LEN(({!Phone_Number})) >= 10 && LEN(({!Phone_Number})) <=
14&&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(({!Phone_Number}),
'(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '')) =
10&&ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(({!Phone_Number}),
'(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '')))

Please guide me if I am doing anything wrong here.



did we got any solution for this?

Yes,i used regex :  "REGEX({!Phone_Number}, "^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$")"

Thanks for the answer. The regex works , however the validation message shown on the mobile is not same as the validation message defined. It gives this generic error 'Unable to validate field...'. Is this a limitation?

That seems like FSL is unable to validate your input with the formula you used. Please share a screenshot so that I can see what you configured.
